# How to checked angular material checkbox if value matched

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material

How to compare 2 array of objects and when value is matched then checked angular material checkbox? eg: In this case `operator` object is matched so checkbox is checked for operator

**app.ts**

```
const arr1 = [ 
   { 
      "id":"1",
      "name":"operator"
   },
   { 
      "id":"2",
      "name":"admins"
   },
   { 
      "id":"3",
      "name":"client"
   },
   { 
      "id":"4",
      "name":"developer"
   }
]
const arr2 = [ 
   { 
      "id":"1",
      "name":"operator"
   },
   { 
      "id":"3",
      "name":"client"
   }
]

this.arr1.forEach(a1Obj => {
    this.arr2.some(a2Obj => {
        if (a2Obj.id === a1Obj.id) {
            console.log(a1Obj);
        }
    })
});
```

**app.html**

```
<div class="col" *ngFor="let group of groups; let i = index">
    <mat-checkbox value="group.id" [labelPosition]="'after'" [checked]="true" (change)="assignGroups($event, group.id)">
        {{ group.name }}
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an array in which you will push the common values and then check everytime if current group exists in commonArray using isCommonElt function:

**TS file**

```
commonArray = [];
this.arr1.forEach(a1Obj => {
  this.arr2.some(a2Obj => {
    if (a2Obj.id === a1Obj.id) {
      console.log(a1Obj);
      this.commonArray.push(a1Obj);
    }
  })
});

isCommonElt(id: any): boolean {
  return this.commonArray.some(elt => elt.id === id);
}
```

**HTML file**

```
<div class="col" *ngFor="let group of groups; let i = index">
    <mat-checkbox value="group.id" [labelPosition]="'after'" [checked]="isCommonElt(group.id)">
        {{ group.name }}
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

**.ts file**

```
const arr1 = [ 
   { 
      "id":"1",
      "name":"operator"
   },
   { 
      "id":"2",
      "name":"admins"
   }
];
const arr2 = [ 
   { 
      "id":"1",
      "name":"operator"
   },
   { 
      "id":"3",
      "name":"client"
   }
];

isEnableCheckbox: boolean = false;

constructor() {
  this.isEnableCheckbox = this.checkIsObjectIsEqual();
}

checkIsObjectIsEqual() {
    // The below resultArray will give the common objects from the both comparing arrays
    let resultArray = this.array1.filter(a1Obj => {
        return this.array2.some(a2Obj => {
            return a2Obj.id === a1Obj.id;
        });
    });

    if (resultArray.length > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**.html file**

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="isEnableCheckbox">some label</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: it's checked all checkboxes

Comment: how the groups array looks?. Could you please paste that code?