# Is there a way to keep only few items checked in mat-checbox on the initial load?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a use case where for eg: I have an array of 10 values but I want a few values out of it to check:

```
<div *ngFor="let base of BaseVersions">
 <mat-checkbox #baseCheckbox (change)='selectBaseVersionsCheckbox(baseCheckbox.checked,base)'
 [(checked)]="baseVersionChecked">
 {{base}} </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Here I have checked the value set to be true by default which keeps all the values in the checkbox checked.

Comment: Try this link. This will answer your question.
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411814/how-to-checked-angular-material-checkbox-if-value-matched)

Answer (score 0):

Using Reactive Form:

### html

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="value" (change)="changeValue($event)"></mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

### ts

```
formGroup = this.fb.group(
    { value: [''] });

changeValue(FieldValue: MatCheckboxChange) {
    // ..... Code on value change
}
```

In your Code Case:

```
<mat-checkbox #baseCheckbox (change)='selectBaseVersionsCheckbox(baseCheckbox.checked,base)'
            [(checked)]="baseVersionChecked" [value]="baseCheckbox.value"
             >
          {{base}} </mat-checkbox>
```